# Unable to perform mouse hover action which clicking on a link

Tags: java, mousehover

I am using www.flipkart.com,where I want to hover over "Appliances" and click on "Television".

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Appliances']"));
    WebElement submenuxpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='Wbt_B2'][2]//li[@class='_1KCOnI _1h5QLb']//a[@title='Televisions']"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(mainMenu).perform();
    //builder.moveToElement(submenuxpath).click().perform();
    //driver.click(submenuxpath);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.close();
}
```

It is able to hover over on "Appliances". But I am getting error in `driver.click(submenupath)` or `builder.moveToElement(submenuxpath).click().perform()`. Where I am going wrong?
driver.click(submenupath) error: The method click(WebElement) is undefined for the type WebDriver. Quick fix : add cast to driver. Even if I am doing add cast,it is not working then. For builder.moveToElement(submenuxpath).click().perform(),no error is coming,but it is not clicking also.

Comment: Please post the actual error messages/stack traces

Comment: driver.click(submenupath) error: The method click(WebElement) is undefined for the type WebDriver.
Quick fix : add cast to driver.
Even if I am doing add cast,it is not working then.
For builder.moveToElement(submenuxpath).click().perform(),no error is coming,but it is not clicking also.

Comment: Please **edit** your question, don't use comments for this.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Dev: Yeah,Its working fine now.I jst fixed the xpath.BTW,Thanks for asking.. :)

Comment: LOL !!! I was just about to Submit the Answer for your Question :) checkout if it works bcuz there are hidden elements :)

Comment: @dev : Thanks.. :)